# Xamarin.Forms Picker causes app to crash

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following code set up. The simulator crashes when I navigate to the view. I am trying to put a picker into my app that displays pay schedules such as Weekly, Semi-Annual, and Annual.

```cs
    insurancePicker = new Picker() 
    {
        Title = "Insurance Frequency",
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
    };
    insurancePicker.Items.Add("Monthly");
    insurancePicker.Items.Add("Semi-Annual");
    insurancePicker.Items.Add("Annual");              
    insurancePicker.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (insurancePicker.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {               
        }
        else
        {
        }
    };
```

I add it to the view like such:

```cs
Content = new StackLayout{
            Spacing = 20, Padding = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 0),
            Children = {
                homeValue,
                amountOwed,
                new StackLayout{
                    Spacing = 2,
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, 
                    Children = {
                        insurance,
                        insurancePicker
                    }
                },
                new StackLayout{
                    Spacing = 2,
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, 
                    Children = {
                        taxes,
                        taxesPicker
                    }
                },
                btnCalculate
            }
        };
```

Below is the stacktrace I get:

> mono-rt: Stacktrace:
>
> mono-rt:   at  <0xffffffff>
>
> mono-rt:   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_int_int_bool
>   (intptr,intptr,int,int,bool)
>
> mono-rt:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIPickerView.Select (int,int,bool)
>   [0x00010] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/build/compat/UIKit/UIPickerView.g.cs:185
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PickerRenderer.UpdatePicker
>   ()
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PickerRenderer.OnModelSet
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer.SetModel
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.RendererFactory.GetRenderer
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewPackager.HandleChildAdded
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<T>,System.Action`1)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewPackager.Load ()
>
> mono-rt:   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer.SetUpEventHandlers
>   (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer.OnModelSet
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer.SetModel
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.RendererFactory.GetRenderer
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewPackager.HandleChildAdded
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<T>,System.Action`1)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewPackager.Load ()
>
> mono-rt:   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer.SetUpEventHandlers
>   (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer.OnModelSet
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer.SetModel
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.RendererFactory.GetRenderer
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewPackager.HandleChildAdded
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<T>,System.Action`1)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewPackager.Load ()
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.ViewDidLoad ()
>
> mono-rt:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke)
>   object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>
> mono-rt:   at  <0xffffffff>
>
> mono-rt:   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper
>   (intptr,intptr)
>
> mono-rt:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x00030]
>   in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/build/compat/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:2232
>
> mono-rt:   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer/d__d.MoveNext
>   ()
>
> mono-rt:   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Startd__d>
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer/d__d&)
>   [0x0001b] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_T.cs:107
>
> mono-rt:   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.OnPushAsync
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool)
>
> mono-rt:   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.PushPageAsync
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool)
>
> mono-rt:   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.OnPushRequested
>   (object,Xamarin.Forms.NavigationRequestedEventArgs)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/d__c.MoveNext ()
>
> mono-rt:   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Startd__c>
>   (Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/d__c&) [0x0001b] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.cs:107
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.PushAsync
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/NavigationImpl.OnPushAsync
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.PushAsync
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.OnPushAsync
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page)
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.PushAsync
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page)
>
> mono-rt:   at FNBMortgageForms.Shared.HomePage.m__1
>   (object,System.EventArgs) [0x00010] in
>   /Users/Projects/FNBMortgageForms/FNBMortgageForms/Views/HomePage.cs:59
>
> mono-rt:   at Xamarin.Forms.Button.SendClicked ()
>
> mono-rt:   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer/<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0
>   (object,System.EventArgs)
>
> mono-rt:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated ()
>   [0x00007] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIControl.cs:33
>
> mono-rt:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke)
>   object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>
> mono-rt:   at  <0xffffffff>
>
> mono-rt:   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>
> mono-rt:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
>
> mono-rt:   at FNBMortgageForms.iOS.Application.Main (string[])
>   [0x00008] in /Users/Projects/FNBMortgageForms/iOS/Main.cs:17
>
> mono-rt:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke)
>   .runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>
> mono-rt:  Native stacktrace:
>
> mono-rt:

Comment: do you have items filled for your `taxesPicker` ?

Comment: You were correct. Was a copy  paste error. I changed everything to be the taxesPicker except the part where you add items. Thanks!

Comment: if it helped, I'll make a proper answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're filling Items for your `insurancepicker` but i don't see you filling `taxespicker`. The error reporting does not give you that information, but having at least one item set is required for a `Picker` to work.